# Python returns MagicMock object instead of return_value

Tags: python, python-unittest, magicmock

I have a python file `a.py` which contains two classes `A` and `B`.

```
class A(object):
    def method_a(self):
        return "Class A method a"

class B(object):
    def method_b(self):
        a = A()
        print a.method_a()
```

I would like to unittest `method_b` in class `B` by mocking `A`. Here is the content of the file `testa.py` for this purpose:

```
import unittest
import mock
import a


class TestB(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('a.A')
    def test_method_b(self, mock_a):
        mock_a.method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A'
        b = a.B()
        b.method_b()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I expect to get `Mocked A` in the output. But what I get is:

```
<MagicMock name='A().method_a()' id='4326621392'>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: When testing, `A()` returns the `return_value` from `mock_A` (a regular `MagicMock`, as you haven't specified anything else), which is not an instance of the class `A`. You need to set that `return_value` to be something that has a defined `method_a`.

Comment: mock_a.method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A' => mock_a().method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A' should be better :)

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR is precisely correct, it's the return value from calling `mock_a` that should have the method, not `mock_a` itself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe . Thanks for your explanation. I just tried. Both `mock_a().method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A'` and `mock_a.return_value.method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A'` worked. Thanks a lot for your comments. Would you please go ahead and put it as an answer?

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi thanks a lot!

Comment: @Niakros, you're welcome :)

Comment: could something like this also work ? `mocker.patch('a.A.some_method_a', RETURN_VALUE="foo")`

that's what im stuck on at the moment. seems that it still swaps magic mock for class A

Answer (score 212, accepted):

When you `@mock.patch('a.A')`, you are replacing the class `A` in the code under test with `mock_a`.

In `B.method_b` you then set `a = A()`, which is now `a = mock_a()` - i.e. `a` is the `return_value` of `mock_a`. As you haven't specified this value, it's a regular `MagicMock`; this isn't configured either, so you get the default response (yet another `MagicMock`) when calling methods on it.

Instead, you want to configure *the `return_value` of `mock_a`* to have the appropriate method, which you can do as either:

```
mock_a().method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A' 
    # ^ note parentheses
```

or, perhaps more explicitly:

```
mock_a.return_value.method_a.return_value = 'Mocked A'
```

Your code would have worked in the case `a = A` (assigning the class, not creating an instance), as then `a.method_a()` would have triggered your mock method.

Comment: @imsrgadich do you need a *mock* for that? Just build the appropriate dataframe, treat it as a test value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, I could do that but I'm also performing df.drop in my called method which I need to assert and over that I'm not returning the dataframe back from called method. That creates a problem. I found a way using `mock_data.configure_mock(columns='my_column')` which solves it. Thanks for the reply though. (ref: https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/how-world-do-you-mock-name-attribute/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you mock two SQLAlchemy models in the same test. The first one works OK, but the second one will return a MagicMock regardless of what you define.

Comment: This explanation is way better than any python documentation. Thank you!

Comment: I am confused what does the parentheses do? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @user13758558 I don't know which parentheses you mean, but In Python they're either grouping (which doesn't appear in this post) or _calling_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67878856/how-to-mock-function-calls-of-s3-boto3-python

Comment: and if you're asking the reason why it works ... that `mock_a()` return a singleton

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. THANK YOU!

Comment: I've set the `return_value` and the `mock` is returned anyways. These mocks are not easy to set up properly

Comment: The first solution, `mock_a().method_a.return_value`, invokes `mock_a` in such a way that `mock_a.assert_called()` becomes true even if `mock_a` is never invoked by the code being tested. The second solution, `mock_a.return_value.method_a.return_value`, does not invoke `mock_a` in that way (`mock_a.assert_called()` remains false). For this reason, I prefer the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

In case of mocking an object I use this syntax:

```
@mock.patch.object(
    a.A,
    'method_a',
    lambda a: "Mocked A")
def test_method_b(self):
    b = a.B()
    b.method_b()
```

In this case the method_a is mocked by the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my return_value was this `{"key1": "value1"}`. So I needed to cast this with `dict()` before applying the patch.

Like this:

```
@fixture
def mock_something(mocker: MockFixture, request: SubRequest) -> MagicMock:
    method_to_mock = f"your_module.YourClass.some_method"
    return_value = dict(request.param)
    if isinstance(return_value, Exception):
        return mocker.patch(method_to_mock, side_effect=return_value)
    return mocker.patch(method_to_mock, return_value=return_value)
```