# Mock class method that is called within another function

Tags: python, testing, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

I want to mock a class method's output, which is called by a function defined in a different module. For example:

**class_module.py**

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def my_method(self):
        return [1,2,3]
    
    def other_methods(self):
        other_func(self.user)
        return "something I do not really want to mock"
```

**function_module.py**

```
from class_module import my_class

def my_fun():
    user = "me"
    foo = my_class(user)
    foo.other_methods()
    return foo.my_method()
```

**test.py**

```py
@patch("function_module.my_class")
def test_my_fun(class_mock):
    class_mock.return_value.my_method.return_value = []
    bar = my_fun()

    assert bar == []
```

However, I am getting an `AssertionError` saying that `[1,2,3] != []`. So I guess the mock is never happening on the method I want. Can somebody explain how to do it? And why is this happening?

**EDIT**

Actually, the implementation shown does not work because the test is starting an entirely separate process. Therefore, no function could be mocked. Sorry for my misconception

Comment: You don't patch a single method, replace the class `@patch("function_module.my_class")` then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199345/3001761.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I tried the other answer you provided. However, I still get the same issue. I updated my question to be more similar to my code

Comment: Your code works for me, the test passes locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) allows patching a specific method of a class.

**class_module.py**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def my_method(self):
        return [1, 2, 3]

    def other_methods(self):
        return "anything"
```

**function_module.py**

```py
from class_module import MyClass


def my_fun():
    user = "me"
    foo = MyClass(user)
    assert foo.other_methods() == "anything"
    return foo.my_method()
```

**test_my_func.py**

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

from class_module import MyClass
from function_module import my_fun


@patch.object(MyClass, "my_method")
def test_my_fun(my_method):
    # given
    any_value = [99, 98, 97]
    my_method.return_value = any_value

    # when
    result = my_fun()

    # then
    assert result == any_value
```

With these files, `pytest test_my_func.py` passes successfully.