# magic_mock_db.connect.assert_called() fails even though it's called

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, peewee, python-unittest.mock, vscode-python

I am using vscode-python's extension with python's unittest to test if `peewee` successfully connects to the database.
This is the class that is being tested:

```py
import logging
from datetime import (datetime, timezone)

# 3rd party libraries
import peewee


log_fmt = "%(asctime)s - %(funcName)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
# enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format=log_fmt,
    level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Freezer():

    db_name = "db"
    db_username = "db_user"
    db_pswd = "db_pswd"

    def __init__(self):
        self.freezer = peewee.MySQLDatabase(
            database=Freezer.db_name,
            user=Freezer.db_username,
            password=Freezer.db_pswd,
            host="localhost",
            port=3306
        )

    def open_freezer(self):
        if self.freezer.connect():
            print('CONNECTED')
```

when called `open_freezer()` will connect to the database and print out `CONNECTED`.
and this is the test suite:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import (MagicMock, patch)

from src.freezer import (Freezer, BaseModel, PlatiniumBotUser, peewee)


class FreezerTestSuites(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_open_freezer(self):
        with patch("src.freezer.peewee.MySQLDatabase", autospec=True) as mock_db:
            self.freezer = Freezer()
            mock_db.assert_called_once()
            self.freezer.open_freezer()
            mock_db.connect.assert_called()
```

in the last line, aka `mock_db.connect.assert_called()` fails with the below `AssertionError`:

```py
test_open_freezer (test_freezer.FreezerTestSuites) ... 
CONNECTED
FAIL
NoneType: None

======================================================================
FAIL: test_open_freezer (test_freezer.FreezerTestSuites)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/db_testing/tests/test_freezer.py", line 23, in test_open_freezer
    mock_db.connect.assert_called()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 882, in assert_called
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'connect' to have been called.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.117s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

As you can clearly see it prints out `CONNECTED` thus indicating that it has called the `connect()` method and successfully connected, but the assertion fails.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `mock_db().connect.assert_called()`? You're calling it on the instance, not the class. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38199008/3001761.

Comment: Or `mock_db.return_value.connect...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), I was calling `connect` on the mocked class `mock_db` instead of what it was supposed to return to the `self.freezer`. The correct way to do it is:

```py
def test_open_freezer(self):
     with patch("peewee.MySQLDatabase", autospec=True) as mock_db:
          self.freezer = Freezer()
          mock_db.assert_called()
          self.freezer.open_freezer()
          mock_db.return_value.connect.assert_called()
```