# With unittest.mock, How to mock a class property with return_value depending on instance attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking

I have two classes `A` and `B`. I want to test function `foo_a` of `A`. Using some business logic, `foo_a` creates two possible instances of `B` (with different arguments) and calls function `foo_b` of `B`:

```py
class A:
  def foo_a(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # some code above
    if condition_1:
      foo_b_result = B(**arguments_1).foo_b()
    else:
      foo_b_result = B(**arguments_2).foo_b()
    # some code below that returns foo_b_result + other objects independent of foo_b_result
```

The problem comes from the fact that `foo_b` is a complexe function that calls APIs and other stuff. I don't want to mock APIs here in this unit test so that `foo_b` returns the appropriate output, indeed, `foo_b` is already tested elsewhere in my set of unit tests for class `B`. Thus, in this context I care more about the correctness of `arguments_1` and `arguments_2` than the correctness of `foo_b_result`. Therefore, It would be nice if I could mock `foo_b` so that it returns outputs that could easily show if `foo_b` has been called with the right instance of `B`. For instance, `foo_b` could return `arguments_1` or `arguments_2`.

Maybe there is another better approach for unit testing `foo_a` in this case, any idea is welcome.

**UPDATE**: Another way would be to create a new function that takes as input `condition_1` and returns either `arguments_1` or `arguments_2` (this function could be tested easily). Then I would mock `foo_b` so that it always return the same value (for instance 0). But still, it would be interesting to know if it's possible to mock `foo_b` so that it returns values according to `arguments_1` or `arguments_2`.

Comment: What do you mean you want to mock `foo`, specifically? Do you mean you want to replace a `MyClass` instance with a test double?

Comment: just edited the question. Clearer ?

Comment: Not really. If you're testing `MyClass` you shouldn't be mocking any part of it. If you're testing something that _uses_ a `MyClass` why not pass it e.g. `MyClass(a=0)`, whose `foo` method would return `0` as desired?

Comment: Could you give a more representative one, then? Are you testing some other part of `MyClass` that _calls_ `self.foo()`, for example? And I'm not sure why you think that's untrue, trying to replace parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing with test doubles makes it much more difficult to e.g. confidently refactor within the class and couples your tests closely to the current implementation.

Comment: alright, I'll make my question more precise then

Comment: OK, thank you. In the meantime here are some concrete examples (albeit in JS) of why I'd generally recommend not mocking within the class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752334/3001761.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe I rewrote the question in a more detailed way. Thanks for your help and the link to your post

Comment: _"show if `foo_b` has been called with the right instance of `B`"_ - no, you need to show if it's been called _on_ the right instance of `B`, which really just means what `B` was called with. You can see how to mock a class at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199345/3001761, then you can assert on what the mock of `B` was called with. You shouldn't need to put real behaviour (_"it returns values according to `arguments_1` or `arguments_2`"_) into the test double for a case like this.

Comment: Oh ok I see. "Then you can assert on what the mock of B was called with" can you develop a bit ? How can I do this ?

Comment: Mocks have a bunch of methods for asserting on interactions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called

Comment: ok I know how check if my Mock's function `foo` was called with some attributes like so: `mock = Mock(MyClass) mock.foo(b=3) mock.foo.assert_called_with(b=3)` but this does not seem to work when I replace `foo` by `__init__`. Thanks for helping

Comment: alriiight `mock = Mock(MyClass) mock(b=3) mock.assert_called_with(b=3)` is what I needed... Thanks

Comment: do you want to make an answer with all the ideas above ? Otherwise I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe I ended up with the following solution:

```py
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

@mock.patch('a.B')  # a.py contains class A with an import of class B
def test_foo_a(mock_b):  # mock_b mocks class B
  return_value_foo_b = "whatever"
  mock_b().foo_b = MagicMock(return_value=return_value_foo_b)
  # instantiate A in a variable called a, then:
  expected_foo_a = (return_value_foo_b,) # + other objects independent of foo_b_result
  assert a.foo_a() == expected_foo_a
  mock_b.assert_called_with(arguments_1)  # condition_1 is met.
```