# Python mocking: basic errors mocking a class using patch/MagicMock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

Although I've successfully used google test and mock successfully for C++, I'm getting nowhere when it comes to using mocking in Python.

I'm trying to mock a small class in my code so that I can ensure the response from a particular function. I want to mock the whole class since the constructor does things that involve dependencies that I'd like to avoid. This seems like a fairly typical and mundane use case for mocking.

However, when I call the function on the mock, what I get is a `MagicMock` object, not the result I wanted. Taking a very simple example:

```
class MyClass:
    def value(self):
        return 10
```

If I want to mock the `MyClass` class and change the `value` function so that it returns a different value, I believed that I could do this as follows:

```
with patch('__main__.MyClass') as MockMyClass:
    b = MyClass()
```

If I then attempt to set the `value` function to something different, it doesn't work the way I expect and calling the function on the mock seems to return a MagicMock object instead:

```
>>> with patch('__main__.MyClass') as MockMyClass:
...     MockMyClass.value = lambda : 22
...     b = MyClass()
...     print(b.value())
<MagicMock name='MyClass().value()' id='140661276636400'>
```

I've been through so many references and examples and I *still* don't get what I'm doing wrong. Feel so clueless - can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in fact very similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199345/258009).

I'm not sure if I'm saying this correctly, but the important bit seems to be that `MockMyClass` is just a `MagicMock`, but what I have to change is not on the `MagicMock` itself but *on the returned value* of the `MagicMock`.

When amended to change the attribute on the `return_value` from `MockMyClass`, it worked out fine:

```
>>> with patch('__main__.MyClass') as MockMyClass:
...     MockMyClass.return_value.value = lambda : 22
...     b = MyClass()
...     print(b.value())
...
22
```